# QGIS 2.8 (openSuse 13.1) pdf export with print composer not working

Tags: qgis, export, print-composer, pdf

I'm using QGIS 2.8 with a openSuse 13.1 system. If I try to export a map (with openlayers-plugin active) with 120 dpi it works fine, but if I change the dpi setting to something higher (like 130 dpi) the map dissapears from the screen and a pdf-file with the size of 0 byte will be created. So after one hour of rendering I aborted the process.

In the terminal the following will be showed:

> [WORKER THREAD] Waiting for the async request to complete
>   Speicherzugriffsfehler (segmention fault)

Are there any missing components (e.g. some python-stuff) I need to install, or other workarounds?

Comment: Try disabling the OpenLayers plugin and retesting. The plugin isn't compatible with the print composer.